# Is there a Mac diagnostics utility for troubleshooting hardware issues?

Tags: mac, hardware, macos

Is there software that helps identify problems, issues, conflicts, etc. with the hardware of a Mac?

I came across [Tech Tool Deluxe](http://www.micromat.com/index.php?Itemid=51&id=37&option=com_content&task=view), which was apparently used in Applecare. Wondering if there was any other hardware diagnostics tool out there.

Comment: [Does anyone know any good Diagnostic tools?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125358/8546) (2014-03-24, closed)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) is a possible solution. Might need some [elbow grease to get it to work on OS X Lion](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/29/get-apple-hardware-test-boot-mode-back-in-mac-os-x-lion/).

Comment: I've got Apple Hardware Test running, but it finds no problems. Still the machine locks up *a lot* (with no logs left behind). Any other tools to recommend?