# Does anyone know any good Diagnostic tools?

Tags: mac, hardware, macos

Does anyone know any good **diagnostic tools** for Mac?
something **inline** with *Apple Hardware Test*, *Apple Service Diagnostics*, *tech tool pro*, preferably more in depth perhaps something *low level, pre-OS-startup*

I need to do a complete hardware test on some MacBooks and one iMac, that is to do a thorough test of all components GPU, CPU, HDD, ODD, logic board, memory. apple hardware test would suffice however i don't have the option to use it on all the machines. if there is somehow a way to download and run it through say an usb thumb drive, this would be ideal.

basically as stated it needs to be ha hardware test similar to apples own hardware test. i need it for situations where i can't run AHT. For *intel MACs*

Also, I do **not** want benchmarks!

Comment: What are you trying to test? GPU benchmarks or just system diagnostics?

Comment: There is Apple Hardware Test (AHT) and also Apple Service Diagnostics (ASD). ASD is not publicly available but sounds more in line with what you may be after?

Comment: thank you both for your replays i was thinking about something inline with AHT and ASD tho AHT can't be used on some macs due to no cd/usb/internet access

regarding the GPU i don't want benchmarks i want hardware diagnostics

Comment: @Macmaniman what are you testing and why? There are tools to test certain things individually but every tests has a function. What function are you looking for/needing?

Comment: @AndrewU. i need to do a complete hardware test on some MacBooks and one iMac, that is to do a thuru test of all components GPU, CPU, HDD, ODD, logic board, memory. 

apple hardware test would suffice however i don't have the option to use it on all the machines. if there is somehow a way to download and run it through say an usb thumb drive, this would be ideal

Comment: you could try `system_profiler`, the Macbooks should have shipped with it on them, so downloading it shouldn't be a huge concern.  I don't know whether iMac ships with it too, though.

Comment: @AlexejMagura make that an answer

Comment: @AlexejMagura , is the output in the CLI any different from what the GUI has?

Comment: @NOTjust--user4304 by GUI, do you mean system information?

Comment: @AlexejMagura system_profiler is a command that you use in Terminal, or the Command-Line Interface (CLI). Whereas every Mac since, I'm pretty sure even before OS X, has had "System Profiler" as a program in the Graphical User Interface (GUI) of the computer system. I'm asking if the output from the command in terminal has any more detail from the output in ".app", or if it's all the same. Maybe there are flags that can be used to make the command more useful if that is the case by default.

Comment: @NOTjust--user4304 I dunno, there _are_ flags that you can specify on the command-line, but I don't understand why you'd want to use a GUI when the CLI version will probably be more verbose, and even if it isn't more verbose, on the command-line you can pipe the output of system_profiler to something like `sed`, `grep`, or some other tool to make it easier to find crap.  I should, however, mention (as a disclaimer) that I'm a server admin, so I'm kind of biased in favor of the command-line.

Comment: I'd like to put a [pause on this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-can-be-done-to-improve-this-question) to see if it needs to be a CW post or if it can be tightened up. Mac are broad. One tool that works for PPC macs might be worthless or harmful for another Mac. Similarly - is this software or hardware that's being diagnosed? I worry that some great answers are going to be hard to find based on the vague wording in the question (also evidenced by the comment volume trying to understand what the bounds for this are).

Comment: @bmike as stated it needs to be ha hardware test similar to apples own hardware test. i need it for situations where i can't run AHT. pretty simple

Comment: *Why*/*In which situations* can't you run AHT?

Comment: for example in some cases you need a cd witch you don't always have access to

Comment: Very true.  After I put my chosen Linux distro on my first laptop (some 100 distros after the realization that the OS I'd always wanted actually existed), my optical disc drive subsequently went the way of the world; so I had to become accustomed to using USB drives/Disc Images (ISOs) for everything from boot-images to the install discs for video games.

Answer (score 9):

The likelihood that a single tool or utility will provide all of the diagnostic capabilities that you are looking for is *very* slim; if you do happen to find such a utility, there's a decent chance that its support for said capabilities will be shallow.  So while it may seem like a good idea to try to find a really generalized and versatile hardware diagnostics app, you'll probably be better off with getting smaller more specialized apps that are designed to only check *one to a few* of your system's hardware components.

In addition, some hardware components such as your system's PSU (power supply unit) are best checked with specialized electrical equipment designed to check for faults in your PSU, such as your PSU is no longer capable of sustaining the level of Watts your system requires.

#### Hardware Health Diagnostic Applications

Hard-Disk/Solid-State Drive

1. [SMARTReporter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/smartreporter/id509148961?mt=12)

   - User Interface is kinda compact (feels a bit overwhelming with everything squished together).
   - $4.99
   - Available in the App Store.
2. `smartmontools`

   - primarily command-line *only*, GUI depends on the X Server,but even if you do have XQuartz installed, GUI doesn't show up. (Check man page for usage details: `man smartctl`)
   - Free
   - Install via [brew](http://brew.sh): `brew install smartmontools`
3. [DriveDx](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/drivedx/id526290112?mt=12)

   - Much nicer UI than SMARTReporter, feels much cleaner and less *in your face*.
   - Lots of statistics and info presented in a *take your time* kinda way.
   - $19.99
   - Available in the App Store.

Memory (RAM)

<sub>**NOTE**

I couldn't find much in the App Store with a few quick searches, but I do know of a couple different RAM diagnostic utilities, however, all of them require the use of a USB or a floppy or some other media type that can be booted into; while I have experience with at least one of these, I have never used any of these under Mac OS X.  So you're on your own.</sub>

1. [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com)

   - Free and Premium versions available
   - Supports both Windows and Mac

     <sub>Check out [passmark.com](http://www.passmark.com/index.html) for other applications of a diagnostic/forensic nature</sub>
2. [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org)

   - Free (and open-source)
   - Based on the previously mentioned memtest86.
3. memtester

   - A memory (RAM) stress-tester.
   - Free
   - install via brew: `brew install memtester`
   - see man page for more details: `man memtester`

Also, while this may sound super silly, I'd invest some time in checking the contents of your systems' logs, like `tail /var/log/system.log`, however, if I were you I'd check everything in `/var/log` just to make sure that you aren't missing anything.

In addition, be sure to run and check the output of `sudo dmesg | less`: in my experience, if your system is experiencing problems, there's a high likelihood that `dmesg`'s output will shed light on the situation.

#### Mac OS X boot-time keyboard shortcuts (in no particular order):

1. Hold down <kbd>D</kbd> during startup

   - Takes you to Apple's Hardware Test utility (or Apple Diagnostics, depending on Mac model)
   - <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> can be used instead to try starting up Apple Hardware Test or Apple Diagnostics over the internet
2. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during startup

   - Clears the *PRAM* (parameter RAM) and *NVRAM* (non-volatile RAM): if either the PRAM or the NVRAM become corrupt, problems will ensue.  Hold the keys down until your computer restarts: release the keys after you hear the second startup sound.
3. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> down during startup

   - This will load the *boot menu* allowing you to boot to a different operating system partition you may have installed on your hard drive.  May also allow you to boot to a USB, but that's just a conjecture.
4. Hold down <kbd>N</kbd> during startup

   - if your setup includes a compatible network server (NetBoot), you can hold down the said key during boot to attempt a network boot.  You can alternatively use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> keys during startup to start from a NetBoot server using the default boot image provided.
5. Hold down <kbd>T</kbd> during startup

   - puts your Mac into *Target Disk Mode*, effectively turning your computer into a large removable flash drive.  (Allows you to transfer files to and from your machine with... *ease*?)
6. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> during startup

   - Boot into safe mode.  Very similar to Windows Safe Mode; a great way to troubleshoot OSX applications and extensions that aren't working properly.
7. Hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> during startup

   - Boot into verbose mode.  A terminal-like interface will appear while booting.  It will contain information important to startup, allowing you to diagnose startup problems by seeing any errors that may be occurring during startup.  Verbose mode exits automatically when your mac finishes booting.
8. Hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> during startup

   - Boot into single user mode.
     **NOTE** A knowledge of bash and the command-line (in general) is recommended.  Handy for advanced startup sequence troubleshooting.

Also, I'd check out [Parted Magic](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=partedmagic) and [GParted](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=gparted), as well as any other distribution of Linux that offers a Live-disc version.  These can be used to ease the diagnostics process since they're (at least Parted Magic and GParted) are designed with system maintenance in mind--not to mention the fact that you'll have access to a far larger software repository with any given Linux (that has a package manager) than you would with brew, for example.

Comment: these seem to be a great apps for readin your performance
however i would like to know that everything works perfectly at a hardware level

you've listed some great apps tho however! and thank you for that

Comment: @Macmaniman if you just want to make sure that everything is working _as expected_, I would check your system logs.  Are you experiencing any hardware problems/issues in particular that you could, for example, describe? Or are you just looking for apps that could be used to find the source of said errors in the event that they were to occur?

Comment: say for example i want to buy a computer second hand, i want to make sure everything works properly, without spending hours of checking and loading each component. or say for service, if your computer is having issues.

Comment: also, your answers are great. tho it doesn't really answer solve my issue :(

Comment: @Macmaniman Also, are you looking for tools that _stress-test_ hardware or tools that just check to see that the given hardware is able to operate at full capacity and capability?

Comment: really more of a test to see if its operating correctly and Yup at full capacity!

Comment: @Macmaniman, k so I haven't edited my answer since yesterday, I believe, but the applications I now have listed: "those _are_ the droids you're looking for"?

Comment: i can see that and i really appreciate it, i would like to give a right answer just for effort, its a third party app, witch is perfect, but as far as i can see however, it only covers the hard drive and memory

Comment: @Macmaniman when I get off work, I'll see about adding sections for ODD (optical disc drive), GPU, CPU, and if I come across anything else (like something for checking your motherboard) I'll add that too.

Comment: thank you so much, if all that is added you got my vote!

Answer (score 3):

You can access [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) or [Apple Diagnostics](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781) by restarting the computer while holding down <kbd>D</kbd>

You mentioned [Tech Tool Pro](http://www.micromat.com/products/techtool-pro), which I haven't used for like a decade, but it was pretty good back then. I don't know of any software out there that is more comprehensive.

Other software you might try, but I don't think these really do what you want, they are more aimed at data recovery and file system verification:

[Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/index.php) - Free

[Disk Warrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) - Commercial

Comment: thank you however apple hardware test is not an option, perhaps i wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 2):

- Running an OpenGL game has been a good benchmark for me. Artifacts and framerate drops can reveal issues with your GPU. A frame of reference would be ideal, but if you're not a gamer, and weren't playing any games before your concern arose, you might be hard pressed to find an identical HW/SW setup to compare.
- Various benchmarking apps out there, some with specifics to graphics processing, kinda like [Geekbench](http://www.primatelabs.com/geekbench/). Then possibly comparing to similar systems on the web for specs, if there isn't a DB of results for your chosen app out there already. If it's way too far off the middle for your system, probably an issue, mb one specific to your card, maybe somewhere else (hangs, slowdowns, etc. can be caused by almost any component, the trick is to eliminate possibilities).

  - [Novabench](http://novabench.com/) is kinda comprehensive for more than just GPU (CPU, RAM, Disk).
  - [Cinebench](http://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinebench/) is for CPU & GPU benchmarking.
  - [Xbench](http://xbench.com/) is in dire need of an update. for discussion and workarounds see: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10081/xbench
- There could also be some manufacturer/model specific apps and/or firmware updates. Nvidia has many updates for its drivers that Apple doesn't always include with OS updates.

P.s. It helps sometimes to know what HW/SW setup you have for questions like this so helpers can be more specific on top of the general info.

Finally, as an anecdote, the vast (did I say vast?) majority of major Mac failures in my work have been GPU related. Do we blame Apple or Nvidia/ATI? I'd say both. *Insert rant here.*

Comment: hahah great answer thank you for that however as stated I'm more in a need of a Hardware diagnostic rather than a Benchmark test, i can see your logic behind it however its not what I'm looking for

Comment: try dwightk's suggestion of holding down "d" after reboot. This works with some models, but without knowing which you have, we can't tell you for sure. I think most ~2008+ have AHT built in. Apparently I wasn't coherent enough last night because it was supposed to be my first bullet… doh.